# Vaadin CleanupServlet Addon support for Vaadin 14 or Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14, vaadin23

There is an add on https://vaadin.com/directory/component/cleanupservlet-add-on/discussions for cleanup of the session which is supported till Vaadin 8+

Can it be still used for Vaadin 14 or 23? Any equivalent available ?

Answer (score 0):

The add-on will not work for Vaadin 14 or 23, as it's relying on [the `CleanupServletService` implementation being in the same package as `VaadinServletService`](https://github.com/Ansku/CleanupServlet/blob/master/cleanupservlet-addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/CleanupServletService.java#L15-L16), which is `com.vaadin.server` with Vaadin 7 and 8. Since Vaadin 10, [`VaadinServletService` is located in the package `com.vaadin.flow.server`](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/master/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServletService.java#L17). You could probably take the add-on's sources and modify it to work with Vaadin 10 and later.